# Ruby on Rails looking for value from key in devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, customization, custom-component

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I installed devise on my application. I was wondering where I can customize the values if a value is given in `views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`

for example:

```
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
```

this gives out an input and a label, the label is `* Password confirmation`. How do I customize this label and the input field?

Thanks

Comment: You can customize the Devise views by [following these instructions](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-views) in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true, :label => 'something', :class => 'something' %>`

Define the something class in CSS and you'll be fine.

And of course, generate the partials via copying from devise directly or using its generators. I usually copy them from devise repo since I am not that much fan of generators, sometimes they generate files I don't even need or want.

Answer (score 1):

```
rails generate devise:views users
```

You will need to generate the partials first. After that you can use those generated files to override the default ones. Also, it might be good to build the authentication from scratch the first time in order to better understand the process.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch